# Google drive sharable link showing in my local language, not in English

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm developing an application related to Google Drive. So I'm facing an issue when generating a sharable link in Google Drive for a uploaded document. I have written a file uploading script in PHP and file is adding to google drive successfully. My drive language is in US English. But once I generated the link and goes to download page, it's showing in my local language. Not in English. What's the reason for that?

Comment: Could you share a sample link?

Comment: Yes sure.This is a sample link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4fL3-BR-LB5bHQ4M3p2MFNrXzA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It's English. Probably some where in your settings related with Google or Google Drive is your local language. In my case it's English.

Comment: Is it?ok thanks.I have installed microsoft unicode package for my local language in my local machine.Sometimes it can be the issue then.